# Setbuf function in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls, strace

Program 1:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        printf("Hello\n");
    }
```

Output:

```
    $strace ./a.out
    ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
    fstat64(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 3), ...}) = 0
    .
    .
    .
    .
    write(1, "Hello\n", 6Hello
    )                  = 6
    exit_group(6)                           = ?
    $
```

Program 2:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        char buf[2];
        setbuf(stdout,buf);
        printf("Hello\n");
    }
```

Output:

```
    $ strace ./a.out 
    ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
    fstat64(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 3), ...}) = 0
    .
    .
    .
    .
    write(1, "Hello\n", 6Hello
    )                  = 6
    exit_group(6)                           = ?
    $
```

My requirement is to find the use of setbuf function. So, I experimented two programs which is showed above. In program 1, I didn't 
set the buffer to stdout. So, it uses the inbuilt buffer. The size of inbuilt buffer is 4096(Approximately). For that, Hello is enough for
single write. So, write system call will be called only once.

But In program 2, I explicitly set the buffer with the size of 2 character. So, printf uses this buffer. So, my expected output is
that the write system should be called for 3 to 4 times. But, the strace output for both of the programs are remain same.

So In program 2, the printf function uses the buffer(buf) are not. If it is used buf, then write system call will be called for 4 times.
So, How to I check how many times my "a.out" program call write function.

Comment: Again, **void main(){}** should be **int main(void){}**

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `setbuf()` does not specify the size of the buffer, it is assumed to be `BUFSIZ`, not `2`, because the function will never see that `2`.

And since most likely `BUFSIZ` is greated than `2` you have a buffer overflow!

That's quite inconvenient, and that's why there is the new `setvbuf()`:

```
int setvbuf(FILE *stream, char *buf, int mode, size_t size);
```

That will be used such as:

```
setvbuf(stdout, buf, _IOFBF, sizeof(buf));
```

PS: You should not write `void main()`, use `int main()` instead.

Comment: If I change the value of BUFSIZ macro to 2. Then?

Comment: I assume you'd have to recompile your stdlib for that. BUFSIZ comes from the headers for your standard library which communicate compile-time settings as far as the library is concerned.

Comment: @mohan: No!, `BUFSIZ` is a predefined macro that tells you what buffer size the standard library expects. Changing the macro will not change the library (unless you recompile `libc`, and you don't want that).

Comment: So, How to Recompile the stdlib?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Configuring-and-compiling.html. But seriously, that's no simple task. What the assignmant may have meant (if you can only use setbuf() and not setvbuf()) is to set the buffer to null, effectively setting the mode to unbuffered.

Comment: Is there any other way to experiment my program as I expect.

Comment: @mohan, what are you really after?  Recompiling the standard library is quite a big deal.  Why not just use `setvbuf()` instead of `setbuf()` if you want to explore the effect of having a small I/O buffer?

Comment: @mohan, or if you insist on experimenting with `setbuf()` in particular, then that should probably be done in the context of [its documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setbuf.html).

Comment: @JohnBollinger For realtime purpose I would use setvbuf. But, I'd like to know the difference b/w these two. So far only I tried it. Its OK. Thank you

Comment: @mohan, the only difference between `setbuf()` and `setvbuf()` is that the former assumes default values for two of the parameters accepted by the latter.  Again, read the docs.  *`setbuf()`'s behavior is defined in terms of `setvbuf()`*.

Comment: Perhaps one should add that documentation for library functions (and utilities, and shell-builtins etc.) can these days be found by simply googling "man function-name", e.g. "man setbuf". You probably get a similar result by opening a terminal and saying "man setbuf" there, but that is sometimes more cumbersome and harder to read and you didn't set up LESS as your pager and you didn't export LESS=-X so you cannot scroll up to re-read while you are typing... so just google man setbuf.